# WooCommerce - missing products when viewed by tag

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Has anyone had the same problem as this?

A product tag has a count of 68 products to it but when i view that tag page it only shows 47 products !

another tag has 41 and shows 41, another 160 shows only 147 ??

any idea why this could be happening

much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is because your few of the products has common tag you need to change that or may be some of the tags has same same permalink so you need to check this.If i can see your website url i can help you more.